# Facebook behavior to open applications

Tags: php, facebook

I have a Facebook app developed in PHP. There are a access to app in left side in Facebook Page. I don't know how I can have controll when user click in app.

Sometimes when I click in application:

- The full window load the app in apps.facebook.com
- Facebook only reload the frame in page and load the application.

Is there any way to handle this and always do the same?

And in the application, is there any way to push in link and open in apps.facebook.com and not reload the frame in page? It happens the same as before, sometimes he does it one way and others another.

Answer (score 0):

You won't have any control over the Facebook website that wraps your app. You'll have to figure out how to make your app working with all the different loading scenario.

Answer (score 0):

> "And in the application, is there any way to push in link and open in apps.facebook.com and not reload the frame in page?"

Do you mean to open that link in the current tab and not just in the iframe? If so, try adding target = "_top" to the link.

For the other part, I'm sorry but I can't help

Comment: Thanks! It works. The simplest way is the best way. I continue investigating for the other part.